# How can I upload the file to a desired folder in sharepoint using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am able to upload file to `Documents` in SharePoint. But I want to upload it to a specific Folder. I am not sure how can I do that. Any help will be welcomed. I am using the code below to upload files.

```
def upload_file(ctx, listTitle, path):

    list_obj = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(listTitle)
    folder = list_obj.root_folder
    ctx.load(folder)
    ctx.execute_query()
    files = folder.files
    ctx.load(files)
    ctx.execute_query()

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        file_creation_information = FileCreationInformation()
        file_creation_information.overwrite = True
        file_creation_information.url = os.path.basename(path)
        file_creation_information.content = content
        file_new = files.add(file_creation_information)

        ctx.load(files)
        ctx.execute_query()

upload_file(ctx,'/Documents/reports/',path)
```

The code above works fine for  `upload_file(ctx,'Documents',report)`
but doesn't work for `upload_file(ctx,'Documents/reports',report)` folder. It doesn't work.

Error:

```
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-1, System.ArgumentException', "List 'reports' does not exist at site with URL 'https://sharepoint.com/sites/my_page'.", "404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://sharepoint.com/sites/my_page/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('reports')/RootFolder")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is suggesting that you somehow look for a *list* called `reports`. But you want to get a *folder-object*.

It's not clear which package you're using to connect to sharepoint but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) say that you need to make an api-call like this:

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

"Contents of file"
```

Uploading a file to the *Document* directory is working because it's a folder inside the the default directory *Shared Documents*. You can only access folders inside root with the `.root_folder`calls.

Edit 2: As I don't know which package you're using (probably Office365-REST) you can upload a file using the endpoint above in a normal `requests.post`-function.

Should look like this:

```py
import requests

url = f'https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{specific Folder URL}')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)'

headers = {Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
Content-Length: content-length
}

payload = your_byte_string

response = requests.post(url = url, headers=headers, data = payload}
```